# Google BigQuery authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-bigquery

I want to use Google BigQuery authentication like other Google services (for example, Google sheet).

The auth of Google sheet works on the scope and makes appear to the user a popup like "*The app XXX request the access to your Google Account*" and in this popup, you can see what permission needed by the app.

I would the same auth with Google BigQuery but after I read the docs, looks the code of official PHP client, I can't understand how to make this auth. Is this possible?

P.S. Obviously I tried the flow in the google docs with generated JSON from google developer console and it works fine.

Comment: Just to clarify: Would you like to connect BigQuery to other Google Services? Can you list them? If you want to connect to Google Sheets, there is this doc https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis

Comment: No, I have a web app to interact with BigQuery. The end-user must be logging with a classic OAuth (like a google sheet and other Google services), but I can't do it with BigQuery. I follow the docs and I can logging using a JSON with credentials but I don't want to use this procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible. At least in the way you would like.

When using, let's say, `"native"` GCP products, the OAuth authentication is performed automatically after logging in. This is why you don't are prompted to identify yourself when accessing to your GCS buckets, or when getting into the App Engine Dashboard.

- When you want to grant access to an external user to your project, you run the command `gcloud auth login`. An authorization screen is shown like the one below:

  [image: Authorization screen]

This screen is also shown to `"non-native"` GCP services, such as [BigQuery Geo Viz](https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/), [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/), etc. You are prompt to grant access since these are "external"  GCP features which interacts with your project's internal info.

BigQuery is an integrated GCP service and does not requires OAuth authentication when used via the UI.

If you would like to interact with the BigQuery API's, I highly recommend you to use the [BigQuery Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) which do the authentication method much easier.

However, there is a way to grant access to external users. I found the [Authorizing API requests doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization) where it's said that you can get a **temporal access token** for external users. This is done by following these steps:

1. Run the command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` in a Cloud Shell session.
2. Copy the output and paste it in a HTTP request like

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/datasets?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
   ```

Note that this could lead to even more effort than the required for Client libraries.

Hope this is helpful.